# How to drop all rows where output is 0 and speed is greater than 5 in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in the table, speed and power.  I would like to exclude any 0 for power where speed is greater than 5.

So far I have

```
df[(df.sum(axis=1) != 0)]
```

which will exclude all 0 values but how do I amend that to also exclude all speeds greater than 5, while also including below 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this -

```
drop_idx = df[df.power == 0) & (df.speed > 5)].index

df = df.drop(index=drop_idx)
```

Your `df` will contain all the required rows